# Spring Boot create custom hibernate validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I using Spring Boot with hibernate validator to validate my models, but I wanna to know if its possible to create custom validators (not annotations) I have some complex validation, and I want o validate this using @Valid in my method

tks

Comment: You don't specify what language you're using. That's kind of an essential part of the question ;). Also, you haven't included any code. Stack overflow isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own validation and implement the javax.validation.ConstraintValidator interface to encapsulate the validation logic. When you annotate a field or method with your custom annotation  in a class, and use @Valid on that class, the validation framework will kick in and call your validation logic. Read on here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html